# XSLT: The value of an element is not being displayed

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and am trying to transform an XML output.

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="test" xsi:schemaLocation="test http://reportserver?%2Ftest&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True">

    <Tablix1>
        <Details_Collection>
            <Details>
                <ID>6</ID>
                <Reference>1</Reference>
                <SiteID>PER</SiteID>
            </Details>
        </Details_Collection>
    </Tablix1>

</Report>
```

And this is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"　xmlns:tst="test" exclude-result-prefixes="tst" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="tst:Details">

    <xsl:value-of select="Reference"/>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is returning a blank XML output. Could you please point me to what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly matched the `Details` element using the QName `tst:Details`, but you need to do the same with the `Reference` element, since this is also in that namespace. You need

```
<xsl:value-of select="tst:Reference"/>
```

Comment: Just changing `Reference` into `tst:Reference` will not make it work neither!! This is not the only problem there, give it a try!

Comment: That was the only change needed to the stylesheet, which is what the question was primarily about. Yes, the '&' in the XML input needs to be fixed as well. Changing the namespaces used in the XML is quite unnecessary.

Comment: You will also to switch in the `xsl:stylesheet` element the attributes(namespaces) `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tst="test"` into `xmlns:tst="test" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` -> `SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "xsl:stylesheet" must be followed by
either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Comment: Yes there's a problem in the start tag but I think you misdiagnosed it. There's a stray octet sequence E38080 after the xmlns:xsl namespace declaration. This is `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE character (&#x3000;)` and needs to be replaced by proper whitespace. I assumed that was just something that happened during uploading, perhaps caused by using a too-clever-by-half text editor.